# visual indicator (a +-sign) to expand data in Listview (In MFC)

Tags: c++, visual-c++, mfc

I want to implement a visual indicator (a `+` sign) to expand data in ListView (In MFC). This ListView is part of TreeView control.

Like there is a `+` sign before `Test`, an Array type data, when I will click on the `+` sign it should expand.

### Before

```
+Test
```

### After

```
-
|Test[1]
|Test[2]
|Test[3]
|Test[4]
|Test[5]
|Test[6]
|Test[7]
```

Comment: A TreeView control would be best suited for you, if you don't need any ListView-specific features.

Comment: actually this ListView is part of tree view control....

Comment: Well, for the TreeView you'd only need to add the TVS_HASBUTTONS and TVS_HASLINES styles.